# Full calendar event rendering happens only for particular week

Tags: fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar plugin to display data for one week. The problem is event is rendering only for the week which i select first. Later when i change week events are getting created but are not rendering. When i change again to week I selected first, event creation and rendering both happens. I am using $('#calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', WeekStartDate) to go to desired week.

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: '{}',
        url: 'DataService.svc/CMStrandSelection',
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,

        success: function (data) {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: '',
                    center: '',
                    right: '',
                    height: 300
                },
                defaultView: 'basicWeek',
                editable: true,
                columnFormat: 'DD dddd',
                events:
                    $.map(data.d, function (item, i) {
                        debugger;
                        var event = new Object();
                        event.id = item.eventId; 
                        event.start = item.Start;
                        event.end = item.Endd;
                        event.title = item.Title
                        event.color = 'White';
                        event.allDay = true; //     
                        return event;
                    }),
                eventRender: function (event, element) {
                    //some code
                    });
                }
            });

            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'height', 400);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Solved using  
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('destroy'); 
after the line success: 
function (data) {. 
Hope there is better way to do this.

Comment: Technically there is: 
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/refetchEvents/ and
http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/rerenderEvents/

 But it didn't work for me either so instead i too use destroy. It seams to be fast enough so visually it's great. Ther eis this flash though, when it has the old data, and it takes a moment to load in the new data. What i did was in my SQL (in your case inside CMStrandSelection()) get one month back and forth (in your case one week each way) so when you click the button it already has the data in and it doesn't flash at all ... Hope i make sense.

Comment: Actually i load data for one week at a time but it doesn't flickers.